# PowerShell - Check to See if User is in Group before continuing (Active Directory)

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am writing a script which automatically provisions users in groups when the request is sent off. I am running a check to see if it is in a specific group out of a list or contains a phrase such as HDS. I cannot currently get the "contains" command working quite right for me. Here is what I got:

```
$memberof = get-QADMemberOf -Identity tpatry
if($memberof -contains "HDS" -eq $true){
Write-Host "User is already a member of one of the Job Roles"}
```

When I run this:

```
$memberof = get-QADMemberOf tpatry
Write-Host $memberof
```

I get these groups that I am part of.  This is what $memberof returns:

```
USERS\Domain Users USERS\CCNet-HDS-ADMIN USERS\HDS-CP-STUDENT-ACL USERS\ME-513 USERS\HDS-IT-FTE-ACL USERS\MNE-STUDENTS-O USERS\HDS-ADMIN
```

When I run this, just gives me a new prompt to run another prompt to input my next command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll have to look up the documentation on **-contains**.  Seems like I've seen it before, yet I always overlook, or forget, that one.

Don't know if the main issue has anything to do with what **get-QADMemberOf** is returning?  I don't have that function available to me, checking [online](http://ss64.com/ps/get-qadmemberof.html) looks like it might return a collection/list of objects, instead of a string?  If its not a string, you may need to iterate through each item in the collection at test for the value your looking for.

```
$groups = get-QADMemberOf -identity tpatry
foreach($group in $groups)
{

  # pipe one of them to gm (e.g. $group | gm) to get a list of properties

  if ($group.Name -like "*HDS*" -eq $true) 
  { 
       write-host "found" 
  }
}
```

If the return value **IS** a string, you can try the -like operator:

```
$str = "this is a test"
if ( $str -like "*test*" -eq $true )
{
   write-host "found"
}
```

We can also drop to C# as needed:

```
$str = "this is a test"
if ($str.Contains("test") -eq $true )
{
    write-host "found"
}
```

Comment: I get ***The term 'Get-QADMemberOf' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program*** Where is the cmdlet ? which module ?

Comment: @Kiquenet its been years so you'll have to confirm but I believe it was part of the free Quest Active Directory PowerShell cmdlets.  Dell acquired them and think they can be found here now http://software.dell.com/products/activeroles-server/powershell.aspx

Comment: **Quest Active Directory**  is not the same ***ActiveDirectory*** module https://kiquenet.wordpress.com/2015/01/21/installing-powershell-active-directory-module-for-windows-8-1/

Comment: @Kiquenet the question was asked using the quest active roles commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Name property with a wildcard to return just the groups you're after:

```
$memberOf = Get-QADMemberOf -Identity tpatry -Name *HDS*

if($memberOf)
{
    Write-Host "User is already a member of one of the Job Roles"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "User is not a member of any of the Job Roles"
}
```